# Searching Binary Data in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, binary-data

Using only pure ruby (or justifiably commonplace gems) is there an efficient way to search a *large* binary document for a specific string of bytes?

---

Deeper context: the mpeg4 container format is a 4-byte indexed serialised data structure, without having to parse the structure fully (I can assume it is valid) I want to pull out specific tags.

For those of you that haven't come across this 'dmap' serialization before it works something like this:

```
<4-byte length<4-byte tag><4-byte length><4-byte type definition><8 bytes of something I can't remember><data>
```

eg, this defines the 'tvsh' (or TV Show) tag as being 'Futurama'

```
00 00 00 20  ... 
74 76 73 68  tvsh
00 00 00 18  ....
64 61 74 61  data
00 00 00 01  ....
00 00 00 00  ....
46 75 74 75  Futu
72 61 6D 61  rama
```

The exact structure isn't really important, I'd like to write a method which can pull out the show name when I give it 'tvsh' or that it's season 2 if I give it 'tvsn'.

My first plan would be to use Regular Expressions, but I get the (unjustified) feeling that this would be slow.

Let me know your thoughts! Thanks in advance

Comment: When opening a file in Ruby you can give it the flag `b` for binary, such as `File.open("test.mpg", "rb")`. Would that be helpful?

Comment: is your "large binary document" too big to fit in RAM?

Comment: binary is only needed on windows. FYI

Comment: It's an MPEG4 video, so potentially it could be 8GB, so far too large to fit into memory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, whole file consists of a number of such "blocks" of a fixed structure?

In that case, I suggest scanning one by one, and skipping ones not of interest to you. So, your each step should do the following:

1. Read 8 bytes (using [`IO#readbytes`](http://apidock.com/ruby/IO/readbytes) or a similar method)
2. From the read header, extract the `size` (first 4 bytes), and the `tag` (second 4)

   1. If the tag is the one you need, skip following 16 bytes and read `size-24` bytes.
   2. If the tag is not of interest, skip following `size-16` bytes.
3. Repeat.

For skipping bytes, you can use [`IO#seek`](http://apidock.com/ruby/IO/seek).

Comment: One annoying aspect of the format is that atoms(blocks) can be nested.

Comment: There is this library, haven't used it though: http://github.com/arbarlow/ruby-mp4info

Comment: This has to be the right way forward, this way I don't have to scan through all the atoms I don't actually need (seems most mov files have the metadata at the *end* of the file). Just gotta figure out which atoms to push into! Oh, and figure out why some don't fit the pattern…

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby you can use the `/n` flag when creating your regex to tell Ruby that your input is 8-bit data.

You could use `/(.{4})tvsh(.{4})data(.{8})([\x20-\x7F]+)/n` to match 4 bytes, `tvsh`, 4 bytes, `data`, 8 bytes, and any number of ASCII characters.  I don't see any reason why this regex would be significantly slower to execute than hand-coding a similar search.  If you don't care about the 4-byte and 8-byte blocks, `/tvsh.{4}data.{8}([\x20-\x7F])/n` should be nearly as fast as a literal text search for `tvsh`.

Comment: If I try this in my binary data I get "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)"

Comment: Works if the string is `ASCII-8BIT`. The default is `UTF-8`. You can change it with [`String#force_encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-force_encoding), for instance: `bindata.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")`.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can use regexes against any arbitrary data, including binary strings. HTH.

Comment: Nothing theoretical about it, as long as the regex engine you're using has an 8-bit mode where one byte equals one character.